# how to find even position letters and odd position lettes in a record in ORACLE

Tags: oracle

Please find below the rule of calculating the check digit. The customer number will be 8 digit number. The first 7 digits will be a series and the 8th digit will be a check digit as demonstrated below:

- Add all the odd position digits of the running number
- Add all the even position digits of the running number
- Multiply the sum of above two
- Take the modulo 10 of the sum

So as per the above rule the first account number will be:

- First part : 0030001
- Sum of odd position digits : 0+3+0+1=4
- Sum of even position digits : 0+0+0=0
- Product of above two sums : 4x0 = 0
- Modulo 10 of above product = 0
- The complete account number = 00300010

Second account number:

- First part : 0030002
- Sum of odd position digits : 0+3+0+2=4
- Sum of even position digits : 0+0+0=0
- Product of above two sums : 4x0 = 0
- Modulo 10 of above product = 0
- The complete account number = 00300020

Also the following thing to be maintained in the account number format

- Length each account has to be of 8 digits (seven digit running number and one check digit, the last digit)
- Leading zeros has to be there
- The running number must start from 30001

Comment: Everything is okay...what do you want from this

Answer (score 0):

Taking the `oracle` tag as a hint (and not yet allowed to comment)…

```
WITH
Input (str, note) AS (
  SELECT '00300010', 'OK' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '00300020', 'OK' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '00300025', 'check digit wrong' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '00200010', '< 30001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0300010', 'too short' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '000200010', 'too long' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a0300025', 'not a number' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
  str
  , note
  , CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '\d{8}', '', 1, 1, '') IS NULL AND
        TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(str, 1, 7)) > 30000 AND
        MOD((TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(str, 1, 1)) + 
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(str, 3, 1)) + 
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(str, 5, 1)) + 
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(str, 7, 1)))
          *
          (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(str, 2, 1)) + 
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(str, 4, 1)) + 
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(str, 6, 1))),
        10)
        = TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(str, 8, 1))
      THEN 'TRUE'
    ELSE 'FALSE'
    END valid
  FROM Input
;
```

returns

```
|       STR |              NOTE | VALID |
|-----------|-------------------|-------|
|  00300010 |                OK |  TRUE |
|  00300020 |                OK |  TRUE |
|  00300025 | check digit wrong | FALSE |
|  00200010 |           < 30001 | FALSE |
|   0300010 |         too short | FALSE |
| 000200010 |          too long | FALSE |
|  a0300025 |      not a number | FALSE |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64454/1/0)

Which uses `SUBSTR(str, 1, 1)` to get the respective figures…